# docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://<accountNumber>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com exited with error code 1:

Tags: python, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cdk

I'm simply adopting the Eventbridge ETL design pattern and it gives me this error when I deploy:

[100%] fail: docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://315997497220.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com exited with error code 1:

> ❌ the-eventbridge-etl failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more
> assets. See the error messages above for more information. at
> Object.publishAssets
> (/home/mubashir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/util/asset-publishing.ts:25:11)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at Object.deployStack
> (/home/mubashir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/deploy-stack.ts:237:3)
> at CdkToolkit.deploy
> (/home/mubashir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:194:24)
> at initCommandLine
> (/home/mubashir/.nvm/versions/node/v16.3.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:267:9)
> Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for
> more information.

The steps I took. [Github repo has a video I followed](https://github.com/cdk-patterns/serverless/blob/main/the-eventbridge-etl/README.md)

```
npx cdkp init the-eventbridge-etl --lang=python
cd the-eventbridge-etl
python3 -m venv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
cdk synth
cdk deploy
```

The first error I get is related to bootstrapping. So I bootstrap.

```
export CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1
npx cdk bootstrap aws://315997497220/us-east-2 --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --trust 315997497220 aws://315997497220/us-east-2
```

I've naturally updated the cdk.json file for using the above bootstrapping technique. I've tried all bootstrap techniques, with and without a qualifier, and with its subsequent changes to cdk.json. I don't think it's a bootstrap issue.

**I get the above error and I don't know what the issue is. I have not made any changes to the code.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I geuss you need to get and pipe a password first as you use the `--password-stdin` flag. Try:

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin https://315997497220.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: just executed this before the cdk deploy and it worked.